# Определение координат клика на Canvas в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Когда я делаю `tkinter.Canvas` с полосами прокрутки, то не могу получить верные координаты клика.
Например если использовать `canv.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)`, то координаты `event.x` и `event.y` будут без учета прокрутки `canvas`. Можете помочь и подсказать, какую функцию использовать чтобы получать координаты на `Canvas` c помощью клика с учетом прокрутки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Методы `canvasx` и `canvasy` преобразуют положение на экране (привязывающее отчеты) в фактическую точку на холсте (с учетом прокрутки).

Смотри [doc](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) Scrolling.